# Flat List Error in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Helo guys, I am very new to React Native. I was practicing Flat List. I am putting some static data in  **flatListData.js**  as a JSON format, the actual code is in  **BasicFlatList.js** .  and want to load it in Flat List. But getting error. I am using emulator for output.

Here is my **BasicFlatList.js** file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View,Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import flatListData from '../data/flatListData'


class FlatListItem extends React.Component{

render(){

    return(

        <View>
            <Text>this.props.item.name</Text>
        </View>

    );

}

}

export default class FlatList extends Component {

render() {

    return (

        <View style = {{flex:1, marginTop:10}}>

            <FlatList>

                data = {flatListData}
                renderItem = {({item, index})=>{

                return(

                    <FlatListItem item={item} index={index}>

                    </FlatListItem>

                );
            }}

            </FlatList>

        </View>

    );

}
}
```

Here is **flatListData.j**s file:

```
var flatListData = [
{
    "key" : "t57t76e578tyre8gfret6",
    "name" : "banana",
    "foodDescription" : "healthy",

},
{
    "key" : "t745turehf8er7tr64r",
    "name" : "banana",
    "foodDescription" : "healthy",
}
];

module.exports = flatListData;
```

Here is **index.js** file:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import FlatList from './components/BasicFlatList';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirebaseEmailLoginTest', () => FlatList);
```

And the error: [response error code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfgao.jpg)

Comment: why are you using the Class "FlatList" in its body :D ..

Comment: I would asvise you to read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html again.
Then we'll see about that 500 error code again

Comment: Thank brothers. I have done some mistake, and I recoverd it initially.